# Console.log doesn't work in async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm trying to log a statement in an async function as follows:

```
async generateCharts (insights) {
  const { url } = await this.reportsClient.createReport(insights)
  console.log('url from reports', url)
  return this.parse(url)
}
```

Log statement doesn't show up though, and I'm sure it's because of the async function. Is that correct? Anyway to work around this?

Comment: I just ran your code and it works fine. Have you tried forcing `createReport` to fulfill to verify this?

Comment: FYI, `async` functions are not part of ES6 (ES2015). They *will* part of thies year's release, ES2017.

Comment: @MikeC looks like that would be the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example lacks of context but, IMHO, that's because your createReport function never fulfills.
There are no other reasons why the console.log would not get executed.

Comment: Same here. I had two functions with the same name. The second one took priority while I was editing the first one.

Answer (score 6):

> Note that **errors are swallowed "silently"** within an async function –
>   *just like inside normal Promises*. Unless we add try / catch blocks
>   around await expressions, uncaught exceptions – regardless of whether
>   they were raised in the body of your async function or while its
>   suspended during await – will reject the promise returned by the async
>   function.

[javascript-async-await#error-handling](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await#error-handling)